# Strange Behaviour with Ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I am working on ASP.net MVC 2.0 Application. I am using Ajax form. In that I have a dropdown and a button.

After clicking on button, i wanted to reload the dropdown if the Ajax request is sucessful.

So, i am calling a jquery Ajax function inside the callback function of the Ajax form.

In that jquery Ajax function, I am writing code to get the new data and binding to drop down so that it will be reloaded with new data.

Here, Every thing is working fine for the first time. But, when i click the button for the next time, the Ajax jquery function is called but it is not hitting contoller action method.

Code:

Here, are my jquery functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function GetData() {
            $.getJSON("/Home/GetUsers", null, function (data) {
                var selectList = $("#ddlUsers");
                selectList.empty();
                alert("Inside Get Json method of jquery Ajax");
                var defaultoption = $('<option>').text("--Select--").val("");
                selectList.append(defaultoption);
                $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
                    var option = $('<option>').text(optionData.Text).val(optionData.Value);
                    alert(option);
                    selectList.append(option);

                });
            });
        }
        function Callback() {
            GetData();
            alert("Sucessfully done");
        }
        function Failed() {
            alert("Sorry, an error occured while processing your request");
        }
```

Methods inside Contoller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetUsers()  ----> Method that is called from GetData() Ajax call
    {
        var data = GetUsersList();
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

public SelectList GetUsersList()
{
    Db Fectch

    return data;
}
```

I am unable to understand why the above indicated method is not called for second time yet the GetData() is called.

Please help..

Comment: Could the browser be caching the ajax call and not calling it from the server?

Comment: @whoshotjr ..Surely +1 for your comment.Its true beacuse of the browser cache..it is not calling server..Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the cache, try adding this line before your controller method:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
```

You can also place this line at the top of the controller, if you want it to be applied to all methods.

Comment: @ChtiWi..Superb Worked great..I am have benn breaking my head for an hour..you solved it in a minute..Thanks a lot..